# log4j - Console log all modules in project

Tags: java, log4j

I have a project with several modules:

```
package
  subpackage
     modA.java
     modB.java
     ...
     modZ.java
```

Following some other threads, I've set up a log4j.properties file with the following console appender:

```
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss} %5p [%t] - %m%n
```

I can then manually add the invdividual modules to this appender,

```
log4j.logger.subpackage.modA=DEBUG, A1
log4j.logger.subpackage.modB=DEBUG, A1
...
```

However, this is tedious, especially when renaming or add/removing modules.  **How can I recursively add all modules under `package` to the `log4j.properties` file?**

I've tried:

```
log4j.logger.*
```

to no avail.

Comment: Try to remove configuration of individual modules or try to set `log4j.logger.subpackage=DEBUG, A1`

Comment: Hey that worked, thank you!  Can't believe I didn't think to try this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only `log4j.logger.subpackage=DEBUG, A1`: this will log for all classes and subpackages.

There is also the `rootLogger`:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN,A1
```